# Soft Body crumples upon impact

Tags: physics, soft-body

I have a very simple simulation of a ball falling onto a ground plane. But every time I play the sim, all the ball does is crumple. My settings are down below. Why is it doing this? I want it to be very plasticy.
[image]
[image]

Comment: @BentleyCarpenter It doesn't help at all.

Comment: Try the cloth sim with pressure turned on?

Comment: @ProEffectsMAX I meant that as a joke, but I suppose it wasn't very funny. Could turning on Stiffness do anything?

Comment: @BentleyCarpenter Oh sorry, no offense meant. I'm just not the best at soft bodies

Comment: @ProEffectsMAX Me neither, as a matter of fact. I mostly do hard bodies.

Comment: Increase the *Bending* value

Comment: @Blunder: Please write this as an answer, so that the OP can accept it, and so that we can upvote it! Note: checking or unchecking the "Stiffness" option gets an effect more like a rubber ball, or a blob of JELL-O, respectively.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Increase the *Bending* value (answer was originally in a comment)

Comment: Sorry ... dictionary ... Would be nice to wait a few days, maybe @Blunder wants to write an answer based on his comment.

Comment: @vklidu Oh, sorry. Should I delete it?

Comment: Not necessarily ... I just saw a few yours Answers (also comment of someone) ... it is not necessary to generate answer for such short tip. Comment can be upvoted so others can see useful ones. Or create answer extended about some additional info ... not only copy/paste comment.